# I checked out to a previous commit in git repo. Did some changes and made a commit there. Pushing changes to master branch says everything up to date

Tags: git, github

I checked out to a previous commit in my master branch. Then did some changes and made a commit there itself. Now I wish to push the changes to master branch. But it says everything up-to-date.

In short I did this,

1. `git checkout 573789f3` (a previous commit in master branch)
2. Made some changes there and commited them there itself.

   `git add .`

   `git commit -m "message"`
3. Now when I do `git push origin master`, I get `Everything up-to-date`

Also, I want this commit to be the HEAD of the master branch

Comment: You didn't say why you wanted to start from an older commit on `master`, and therefore the assumption will be that you are unhappy with all the later commits on `master` and you want to get rid of them and replace them with your new commit. I'm just pointing this out in case that isn't what you want, and if not, you probably shouldn't start from an older commit on `master`.

Comment: @GirishGarg if you think my answer is good, can you please approve it as the official answer. StackOverflow is gamified and (only if I deserve it) I want the points to get to 3,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that once you checkout a commit, you are no longer on `master`. So when you push `master` it's up to date because it's unchanged!

Am I right that you want to remove the latest commit, and add a commit of your own.
I would suggest you do it like

```
git checkout master # if you didn't do it already
git reset --hard 573789f3  # Or HEAD~
<do your changes>
git commit -am 'message'
git push --force # The --force will be necessary as you are obliterating the previous HEAD commit
```

Comment: Consider using `--force-with-lease` for a safer alternative to `--force`

Comment: I completely rewrote your first paragraph, because I disagree with it. (I often commit when detached, without warnings even.) And, I think what I replaced it with answers the question better too. I agree with your solution though, which is why I edited your answer instead of writing my own. Of course, please feel free to revert if you don't like my change. :)